# How to fix web page loads half way down page

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce

https://jakke.co.uk/checkout/

when there is something in the basket and you go to the checkout it loads the page half way down and I can't work out why.

need it to load like normal at top of page.

Is a woocommerce site with theme, have tried removing theme override files and it still happens.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you're getting. It appears to work fine for me.

Comment: if you add something to basket and then go to checkout you should see the issue, empty cart is ok.

Comment: I did that before posting my comment. It appeared to work fine. My guess is the issue is browser-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of focus in "Firstname" field of Billing Form.

Just put below code to your theme functions.php file.

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_wc_checkout_fields' );`

function custom_wc_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

```
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['autofocus'] = false;

$fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['autofocus'] = false;

return $fields;
```

}

I hope it will help you.